# Show hide opaque div

Tags: jquery, css

I have an gallery of images which I would like to be faded out to start with and then when a user puts their mouseover the image it fades in to the full image.

I know this is easily done with multiple images etc... but I was wondering if it was possible to use divisions with a transparency set to a certain level when the page loads and then when the user puts their mouse over the image it shows the proper image and fades the div.

In my head it seems quite a simple idea but having trouble finding options that don't involve doubling up on images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}
img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('img').css('opacity',0.5);
$('img').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo of both of the above techniques](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eFSG8/).

---

To target those elements that do *not* match a selector, you can use:

```
$('#jQueryOnlyV2 img:not(".noFading")').css('opacity',0.5);
$('#jQueryOnlyV2 img:not(".noFading")').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':1},500);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':0.5},500);
    });
```

Wherein the selector matches all images that do not have the CSS `class="noFading"` that are contained within the element with an `id="jQueryOnlyV2"`.

This uses the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) CSS3 selector syntax, although the [jQuery `not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) could be similarly used, if you'd rather.

[Revised jQuery demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eFSG8/1/).

Comment: @VincePettit If you want the item to immediately 'pop' to full opacity on mouseover, change the first `500` above to `0`.

Comment: Thanks, how do i apply this to certain images? as some of the navigation images are also faded out which I don't want.

Comment: @Vince Pettit: jQuery accepts CSS-style selectors to target elements. If you post your mark-up I can provide pointers? If you look at the [posted JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eFSG8/) that should offer guidance.

Comment: @Vince Pettit, I'm glad to have helped! =) If you take a look at the revised demo it shows how to select elements that do not have a certain `class` (though it can be applied to `id` too).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#gallery img")
    .css('opacity', 0.2)
    .mouseover(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 100);
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.2}, 100);
    });
```

[See it in action](http://www.jsfiddle.net/4bwQN/)